# Is there any way to identify the particular record which causes error during Export using BCP Command

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, bcp

I have an sql procedure which exports all records from one of my tables to an output CSV file. I have done this using BCP Command. Following is the sample code :

```
SET @v_fileText = 'SELECT ID,FORENAME,MIDDLENAME,SURNAME,DATEOFBIRTH FROM USER_DETAILS'

SET @v_bcpcmd = 'BCP "' + @v_fileText + '" QUERYOUT "' +
                         @v_directory + '\' + @v_filename + '" -S -m0 -t"," -T -c'

EXECUTE @v_filewrite_error = MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @v_bcpcmd, NO_OUTPUT
```

Let us assume that USER_DETAILS has 10 records out of which 8 got successfully extracted to the output file.

This table has another column called status. The records which are successfully exported is expected to have 'DONE' in status column and for failed records it is expected to have 'RETRY'.

Now I want to identify the records which are not extracted to the output file and update one of the STATUS column in the table based on that. Is it possible?

Comment: How is postgresql involved in this?

Comment: I mean, with as little information as youve given me/us, it sounds like youre going to have a manual review of the file and the tables.  My suggestion is to import into a table and use EXCEPT clause against the two sets of data

Comment: Not with `bcp`. You *could* insert all the data into a staging table first, and then try to migrate it to the destination table, you would have better control then.

Comment: @DougCoats What I need to do is create an output csv file which has the entire records from user_details table. So this is not an import task.

Comment: Yeah I know, but youre missing the point. To figure out what didnt get exported, you have to somehow compare those two sets, right? and if you want to do it using sql, then you have to get said set back in there somehow, right?

Comment: @DougCoats actually there is no comparison after exporting the data. This table has another column called status. The records which are successfully exported is expected to have 'DONE' in status column and for failed record it is expected to have 'RETRY'. In order to update this STATUS column, i should get the ids of the failed records and success records.

Comment: Youre literally asking us in your question above on how to verify what columns didnt get exported and then update your table based on that. How else are you going to do that?

Comment: I have asked about the records that didn’t get exported. Not about the columns.

Comment: @sreehari Without a comparison between the two sets of information, your goal is impossible. And it seems HIGHLY unlikely that your export would not include all rows without considering extenuating or more complex circumstances - but bcp does not offer any way to capture what **does not** get into the exported data. You seem to have complexity that cannot be implemented easily or directly with the chosen path.

Comment: Can you share some of the reasons why you must check for lost records? It's not typical, but there are reasons why a row could be lost (and without error I believe). Is possible to address the causes instead? Ultimately, if you have an environment where records can be lost, you MUST add a check or as SMor stated, find a different way to move the data that can capture the errors more easily. There is nothing built into BCP that can do this; you'll have to create more around the BCP command.